# magento 2.3 is that posible to upload file in graphql mutation

Tags: magento2.3, file-upload, graphql

> i wondering is there any way to upload file in magento 2.3.5
>
> via graphql mutation
>
> is there way suggest the way ?

For REST API how we can upload file in magento 2.3?

Comment: Did you find the way to do this?

Comment: Nope ............

Answer (score 2):

I have just created a plugin to upload files to server via graphql. You can checkout here: https://github.com/huykon/magento-graphql-uploader